# AC Plug Type F PCB design?

Tags: pcb, ac, altium, footprint, plug

I am designing a smart plug device. I need an ac plug footprint for my design. I will use type F (schuko) plug but I could not find its design files for altium. Can somebody inform me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is pretty rare that a plug will go directly to a PCB. For various reasons including current handling, robustness, and fault current, you'll usually find flying leads.

Comment: Just create your own footprint.

Answer (score 1):

There's no "standard" footprint for this, because there's no "standard" component. (It's not even 100% what kind of Schuko plug component you'd be referring to, but that makes no difference.)

You will have to find the component you want to use, and look for mechanical models by its manufacturer. Maybe they even offer a footprint library!

More likely, they don't, and you'll have to create that footprint yourself. Since you're about to design a complex device yourself, that's something that you'll have to do sooner or later, anyways, so this is the right time to learn doing if (if you don't know how to do it, yet).